# Make div scrollable in flexbox and size the textarea to the space

Tags: css

Hello I have a Flexbox Container with three childs. The first one has a `textarea` like indicated.
However the `textarea` of the child exceeds the parent element.
It only should be within the parent element in the child.

Second I want to make the content scrollable within child 2 and 3.
Many hours of search could not give me any resolution.

Do you have one?

Thanks in advance for helpful answers.

```css
.flex-rows {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex--1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.parent {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}

.child1,
.child2,
.child3 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: calc(100% - 253px);
}

.child1>*,
.child1>*>* {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}

.child3 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent flex-rows">
  <div>
    <button class="button button1">10px 24px</button>
    <button class="button button2">12px 28px</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex--1">
    <div class="child1">
      <div><textarea></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make content in `.child2` and `.child3` scrollable, you need to set a height `height: 250px;` and `overflow-y: scroll;` on each of the elements.

Additionally, your `textarea` is exceeding the parent because its padding is giving it some extra height. Setting `box-sizing: border-box;` on `.child3 textarea` makes it so the padding is included in the element's height. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

```css
.flex-rows {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex--1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.parent {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}

.child1,
.child2,
.child3 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: calc(100% - 253px);
}

.child1>*,
.child1>*>* {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}

.child3 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
}

.child2, .child3 {
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child1 textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent flex-rows">
  <div>
    <button class="button button1">10px 24px</button>
    <button class="button button2">12px 28px</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex--1">
    <div class="child1">
      <div><textarea></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque auctor ultricies eros id accumsan. Quisque at leo leo. Sed metus quam, dictum nec auctor at, hendrerit et felis. In molestie pulvinar lectus eget feugiat. Curabitur ligula quam, ullamcorper ut pharetra non, vestibulum at nulla. Curabitur vehicula at neque bibendum mattis. Ut cursus libero odio, ac molestie tortor eleifend in. Phasellus quis velit eu metus tristique tincidunt id a nisi. Sed ac massa dignissim eros consequat iaculis et non mi. Suspendisse magna metus, convallis at sollicitudin sed, fringilla eget mi.</div>
    <div class="child3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque auctor ultricies eros id accumsan. Quisque at leo leo. Sed metus quam, dictum nec auctor at, hendrerit et felis. In molestie pulvinar lectus eget feugiat. Curabitur ligula quam, ullamcorper ut pharetra non, vestibulum at nulla. Curabitur vehicula at neque bibendum mattis. Ut cursus libero odio, ac molestie tortor eleifend in. Phasellus quis velit eu metus tristique tincidunt id a nisi. Sed ac massa dignissim eros consequat iaculis et non mi. Suspendisse magna metus, convallis at sollicitudin sed, fringilla eget mi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque auctor ultricies eros id accumsan. Quisque at leo leo. Sed metus quam, dictum nec auctor at, hendrerit et felis. In molestie pulvinar lectus eget feugiat. Curabitur ligula quam, ullamcorper ut pharetra non, vestibulum at nulla. Curabitur vehicula at neque bibendum mattis. Ut cursus libero odio, ac molestie tortor eleifend in. Phasellus quis velit eu metus tristique tincidunt id a nisi. Sed ac massa dignissim eros consequat iaculis et non mi. Suspendisse magna metus, convallis at sollicitudin sed, fringilla eget mi.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Is there a way to calc the required height of the column?
The problem in this example is that the parent div is resize able. 
The parent can get bigger or smaller on click. 
This does not allow me to pass a static height.

Answer (score 0):

Try add overflow-y: scroll; to the textarea

```
    
        .flex-rows {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
    
        .flex {
          display: flex;
        }
    
        .parent {
          height: 250px;
          width: 100%;
        }
    
        .child1,
        .child2,
        .child3 {
          float: left;
          display: inline-block;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
        }
    
        .child1 {
          background-color: blue;
          width: calc(100% - 253px);
        }
    
        .child1>*,
        .child1>*>* {
          width: 100%;
          display: block;
          height: 100%;
        }
    
        .child2 {
          background-color: green;
          width: 100px;
        }
    
        .child3 {
          background-color: red;
          width: 150px;
        }
       .child1 textarea {
       overflow-y: scroll;
       }
    
    
    
        <div class="parent flex-rows">
          <div>
            <button class="button button1">10px 24px</button>
            <button class="button button2">12px 28px</button>
          </div>
         <div class="parent flex-rows">
            <textarea class="child1"></textarea>
            <div class="child2"></div>
            <div class="child3"></div>
          </div>
</div>
        </div>
```